# cannot change to directory with space character in it

Tags: bash, terminal, macos-sierra

This might be related to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/981728/how-can-i-write-space-in-terminal-on-os-x/981776#981776?newreg=e9a3cf6452e446e3a6a908844b106932) but the answers there did not work for me.

I plugged my external HD, then in a Terminal, I type

```
ls /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT
```

This lists files and folders as expected, but then entering:

```
cd /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT
```

throws the following message

```
-bash: cd: /Volumes/TOSHIBA\: No such file or directory
```

What is going on here? How do I change to a directory with spaces via `Terminal.app`?

Here is the context info:

```
uname -vsr

Darwin 17.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar  5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Comment: `type cd` says?

Comment: Have you tried `cd "/Volumes/TOSHIBA EXT"` ?

Comment: poorly defined alias in action? as Ignacio says; what does `type cd` tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT` should normally work.
As a sanity check, you could try this:

```
command cd /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT
```

This will bypass any aliases and functions that may be configured in your environment and interfere. To get to the bottom of why `cd` is not working as expected, try what comments suggested:

```
type cd
```